# Extracting bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, memory-address

In C, 
I have a 32-bit word representing an address (and I have it stored in an unsigned long, hope that's ok). Now from what I gather, part of an address contains the page number and the other part contains the offset. I was wondering how I could extract just the bits that give me the page number. I have already worked out the first 22 most significant bits are the page number and the other 10 bits are the page offset. How can I grab just the bits that are the page number? I am thinking I can do this with some bitwise operations, but am not sure how.

Comment: Good question - I need to do this for a disassembler I'm writing as well.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [bitshift](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html) operators to extract the bits you need.

```
pageNumber = x >> 10;
offset = x & ((1 << 10) - 1);
```

For the page number, the >> operator shifts bits down, so you lose the least signifcant bits.

For the offset, ((1 << 10) - 1) creates a bitmask consisting of 10 ones which is used to select only the 10 least significant bits and ignore the most significant bits.

Comment: It might be a good idea on code like this to mask the bits after you shifted them, in case your hardware does an arithmetic (sign-extending) right shift.

pagenumber = (x >> 10) & ((1 << 22) - 1);

Answer (score 2):

I'm a huge fan of the "two shifts" method of field extraction.  It works both signed and unsigned. To extract a field of width `w` with least significant bit `lsb` from `word`:

```
#define BITSIN(W) (8*sizeof(W))
return (word << (BITSIN(word) - (lsb+width))) >> (BITSIN(word) - width);
```

In this case, `BITSIN(word) == 32` and `lsb+width == 32`, so as long as the word in question is unsigned, you can just shift right 10 without masking.

One caution: **beware 32-bit shifts on 32-bit types**!  The C standard lets the compiler do anything, and what the common Intel chips do is not useful:  `x << y` shifts `x` left by `y % 32` bits (provided `x` has a 32-bit integer type).  This means if you try to shift a 32-bit integer left or right by 32 bits, the result is the same as a no-op.  There is a similar issue with 64-bit shifts of 64-bit types.

Comment: "what the common Intel chips do is not useful" - what do they do?

Comment: @ASHelly: good question; I edited the answer.  Who knows, it might get me an upvote :-)